# Javascript Timer Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: javascript, timer

I currently have a javascript timer that is not working correctly. A Two minute timer should start once the start timer button is clicked. here is my code

HTML

```
 <div id="countdown"></div>
 <div id="notifier"></div>
 <input type="button" onclick="startTimer()" value="Start Timer">
```

JS

```
function startTimer() {
userInput = 120;
if(userInput.length == 0){
alert("Please enter a value");
} else {
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
function display( notifier, str ) {
document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
}

function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
}

function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
(function countdown() {
   display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));         
   actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
   (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
})();
}

setTimer(userInput, {
60: function () { display("notifier", "1 Minute Remaining"); },
30: function () { display("notifier", "30 Seconds Remaining");        },
 1: function () { display("notifier", "   ");        },
 0: function () { alert( "Time Is Up. Please Sumbit Vote.");       }
 }); 

}
}
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/8mmqxsto/​

Comment: Really, you couldn't figure that one out! You've set the Fiddle settings to `onLoad` when it should be `no Wrap` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8mmqxsto/2/**

Comment: The clue to the root of your problem that I presume you missed is visible through your browser's dev-tools console – *Uncaught ReferenceError: startTimer is not defined*.

Answer (score 1):

When you define inline event handlers on your html you must be sure that your js was loaded early (just before the dom loads):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="yourScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="startTimer()" value="Start Timer"> 
    </body>
</html>
```

In your fiddle, configure it to be loaded in `<head>`